# How to connect Samsung galaxy S9 plus to internet while phone is locked and notification bar is also locked and I have forgotten pattern lock

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, unlock, samsung-knox

I have forgotten my phone's pattern lock now in order to unlock it there is one option I know is by using Samsung account I can unlock it but unfortunately my phone's notification bar is locked and phone's ADB debugging is also off, so how can I make my phone online. I don't want to hard reset as it will erase my data in the phone so please if anyone know how to connect a locked phone to internet please tell me and also let me know if you know how to break pattern lock without losing data. thank you so much.

Comment: You can try connecting it with an ethernet cable and a USB-C to ethernet adapter.

Comment: I have tried it already but doesn't work. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.